# DBPedia Query problem

Tags: dbpedia

I am really getting crazy with DBPedia... I thought you did not need to be an engineer to run a query against it, but did not suceed after X tries and hours of reading...

Can anyone be so kind and help me with the following:

I would like to run a query, that gets me the state/region/province of a town.

E.g. for "Miami", that would be Florida. Or for "Bonn" "Northrhine-Westphalia", etc. pp.

Is there any easy to use interface for DBPedia that spits out the queries? Its a pitty such a great resource is so hard to use...

Answer (score 0):

I know its late, but I saw your question in the "Similar Questions" section

I stumbled upon this: http://querybuilder.dbpedia.org/
and this: http://dbpedia.org/sparql

and you'll find some links to tutorials and examples on this blog post as well: 
http://www.snee.com/bobdc.blog/2007/11/querying-dbpedia.html

Comment: It has been some time since I used dbpedia, did my answer here help you solve your problem?